# JSP/JSTL using or not using <c:out> tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i'm helping develop a java jsp jstl based web service and all dynamic objects are being inserted using `${object.foo}` and i was wondering if it made a difference whether or not it was actually in `<c:out value="${object.foo} />`?

the pages all load correctly, but i wonder if there is something that i'm not seeing that may be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you use [JSTL core out](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag, you have some more options:

- The values that you are passing to
  the tag will be by default
  XML-escaped
- You can provide a default value which
  will be displayed if the value passed
  is null.

Answer (score 4):

Use EL expressions, and if you need output escaping then use the `fn:escapeXml` function like `${fn:escapeXml(myText)}`.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of jsp it was not possible to directly use el expressions in text content, you had to use c:out. This is no longer neccessary, using el expressions directly for output creates a much less cluttered jsp in my opinion. The c:out tag still has its uses if you need to control output escaping via the escapeXml attribute.