# <c:set var="s" value="class=\"selected\"" scope="request"/> sets unexpected String in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have some links in my JSP page and I want to make the selected link **Bold**. I have CSS as :

```
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
```

and my JSP Code is :

```
<li <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${subject.subjectId == param.subj_id}">
    <c:set var="s" value="class=\"selected\"" scope="request"/> <!-- Here I'm setting class=selected
    <c:out value="${s}"/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>><a href='/super-context/view-controller?action=view-content&subj_id=
    <c:out value="${subject.subjectId}"/>'>
    <c:out value="${subject.subjectName}" />
    </a></li>
```

But above code does not work and when I go to page-source I see the line below

```
<c:out value="${s}"/>
```

prints :

```
<li class=&#034;selected&#034;>
```

please tell how to get this in :

```
<li class="selected">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:out>` escapes special characters such as quotes.

If you don't want that, you can turn it off:

```
<c:out value="class=\"selected\"" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `escapeXml` is true, and the `<c:out>` tag thus escapes the HTML If you don't want to escape, you could simply use

```
${s}
```

instead of

```
<c:out value="${s}"/>
```

There is no need of `<c:out>` at all in your case. Do it in the same way for all the `<c:out>` tag.

---

`c:out` escapes HTML characters so that you can avoid **cross-site scripting**.

For more info have a look at below posts:

- [JSP/JSTL using or not using  tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423598/jsp-jstl-using-or-not-using-cout-tags).
- [In JSTL/JSP when do I have to use  and when can I just say ${myVar}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574776/in-jstl-jsp-when-do-i-have-to-use-cout-value-myvar-and-when-can-i-just)