# Print a list using java and html in a jsp

Tags: java, html, list, jsp, servlets

I am trying to print a list into a table using java and html, but I am not able to do it. I am using servlets and JSP.

I have the following code:

This is the servlet:

```
    public static List<Receta> getAllReceipes() {
    List<Receta> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String log4jConfPath = "C:/Users/Karen/workspace/Jena/src/Tutorial/log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    try {
        //opening owl file
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Karen/Desktop/Proyecto/bbdd.owl"), null, "TTL");
        //System.out.println(model);

        //create a new query
        String queryString
                = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                + " PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                + " PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                + " PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
                + " PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                + " SELECT ?r ?cal ?tiempo ?dif (COUNT (distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?cantIng) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?modoPreparacion) as ?Preparacion) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?listaIngredientes) as ?listaIng)   "
                + "  WHERE { "
                + "  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta."
                + "  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                + "  ?x rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente."
                + "  ?x rec:modoPreparacion ?modoPreparacion."
                + "  ?x rec:listaIngredientes ?listaIngredientes."
                + "  ?x rec:Calorias ?cal."
                + "  ?x rec:tiempoPreparacion ?tiempo."
                + "  ?x rec:dificultad ?dif."
                + "  } "
                + " GROUP BY ?r ?cal ?tiempo ?dif";

        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        //execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        //print query results
        while (results.hasNext()) {

            //System.out.println(results.getResourceModel());
            //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, q);
            QuerySolution qs = results.next();


            Receta rec = new Receta();

            rec.setNombreReceta(qs.getLiteral("r"));
            rec.setCantidadIngredientes(qs.getLiteral("cantIng"));
            rec.setIngredientes(qs.get("listaIng"));
            rec.setModoPreparacion(qs.get("Preparacion"));
            rec.setTiempo(qs.getLiteral("tiempo"));
            rec.setCalorias(qs.getLiteral("cal"));
            rec.setDificultad(qs.getLiteral("dif"));

            list.add(rec);

            System.out.print(rec.getNombreReceta());
        }

    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Query Failed !");
    }
    return list;
}
```

I also have a Receta class:

```
@Table
public class Receta implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column
private Literal nombreReceta;
@Column
private Literal cantidadIngredientes;
@Column
private RDFNode ingredientes;
@Column
private RDFNode modoPreparacion;
@Column
private Literal dificultad;
@Column
private Literal tiempo;
@Column
private Literal calorias;

public Receta(){}

public Receta(Literal nombreReceta, Literal catidadIngredientes, RDFNode ingredientes, RDFNode modoPreparacion, Literal dificultad, Literal tiempo, Literal calorias) {
    this.nombreReceta = nombreReceta;
    this.cantidadIngredientes = catidadIngredientes;
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
    this.modoPreparacion = modoPreparacion;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.tiempo = tiempo;
    this.calorias = calorias;
}

public Literal getNombreReceta() {
    return nombreReceta;
}

public void setNombreReceta(Literal nombreReceta) {
    this.nombreReceta = nombreReceta;
}

/**
 * @return the catidadIngredientes
 */
public Literal getCantidadIngredientes() {
    return cantidadIngredientes;
}

/**
 * @param catidadIngredientes the catidadIngredientes to set
 */
public void setCantidadIngredientes(Literal cantidadIngredientes) {
    this.cantidadIngredientes = cantidadIngredientes;
}

/**
 * @return the ingredientes
 */
public RDFNode getIngredientes() {
    return ingredientes;
}

/**
 * @param ingredientes the ingredientes to set
 */
public void setIngredientes(RDFNode ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
}

/**
 * @return the modoPreparacion
 */
public RDFNode getModoPreparacion() {
    return modoPreparacion;
}

/**
 * @param modoPreparacion the modoPreparacion to set
 */
public void setModoPreparacion(RDFNode modoPreparacion) {
    this.modoPreparacion = modoPreparacion;
}

/**
 * @return the dificultad
 */
public Literal getDificultad() {
    return dificultad;
}

/**
 * @param dificultad the dificultad to set
 */
public void setDificultad(Literal dificultad) {
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
}

/**
 * @return the tiempo
 */
public Literal getTiempo() {
    return tiempo;
}

/**
 * @param tiempo the tiempo to set
 */
public void setTiempo(Literal tiempo) {
    this.tiempo = tiempo;
}

/**
 * @return the calorias
 */
public Literal getCalorias() {
    return calorias;
}

/**
 * @param calorias the calorias to set
 */
public void setCalorias(Literal calorias) {
    this.calorias = calorias;
}

}
```

With the constructor and getters and setters for each variable.

And the jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./BuscarRecetaServlet" method="POST">     
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th><FONT FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE=3> NombreReceta </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> CantidadIngredientes </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Ingredientes </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> ModoPreparacion </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Calorias </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Tiempo </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Dificultad </th>
        </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${AllReceipes}" var="receipt">        
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.nombreReceta}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.cantidadIngredientes}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.ingredientes}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.modoPreparacion}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.calorias}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.tiempo}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${receipt.dificultad}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I also have an other class where I save the results in a list.

I would like to get something like this:

```
NombreReceta  CantidadIngredientes Ingredientes  ModoPreparacion  Calorias  Tiempo Dificultad
ReceipeName1   10                  Tomato,egg... Clean the tomato..  70        20  3
ReceipeName2   13                  Tomato,egg... Clean the tomato..  40        10  2
```

On the contrary, what I actually have is all the values in a same row, and I don't know how to print it properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some style to the page,
something like this:

```
<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

to get rid of all those FACE,SIZE,BORDER ,etc.

Also you are messing with tags.
The following example should clear your ideas, hopefully:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>table header1</th>
    <th>table header2</th>
    <th>table header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column value</td>
    <td>column value<</td>
    <td>column value<</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column value<</td>
    <td>column value<</td>
    <td>column value<</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

your for-loop should look like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${AllReceipes}" var="receipt">
        <tr>
            <td>${receipt.nombreReceta}</td>
            <td>${receipt.catidadIngredientes}</td>
            <td>${receipt.ingredientes}</td>
            <td>${receipt.modoPreparacion}</td>
            <td>${receipt.calorias}</td>
            <td>${receipt.tiempo}</td>
            <td>${receipt.dificultad}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

EDIT:

your Dao method should look similar to this:

```
 ...
 List<Receta> recetas = new ArrayList<Receta>();

   query = "SELECT * FROM  RecetaTable";
        stmt = dbCon.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Receta rec = new Receta();
            rec.setNombreReceta(rs.getString("nombreReceta"));
            // and so on
            recetas.add(rec);
        }

        return recetas;
```

Comment: I updae my code, and I changed the tags. But now it seems that its not going into the for cause I have no result. Its just printing the table, but empty. I can´t see what am I doing wrong, thanks

Comment: First of all, thanks. I did as you said, but I still have the empty page. When I print the value of AllReceipes then I have all the information, but its not getting into the for each.

Comment: Yes, I thought you only posted part of your Receta class, but if that's the entire class that's a problem because you need a getter method for each of the fields. example: public String getNombreReceta()

Comment: I do have a getter and setter of each value in Receta. Iam going to put it here just in case there is something wrong there than Im not able to see, thanks for your help

Comment: what does your RecetaDao.getAllReceipes() method return ?

Comment: It does return a List. I put the code on my question

Comment: Actually, no, its just a List.

Comment: That's the problem I guess, I'm going to make another Edit

Comment: Not yet, I was trying to change some things, but I cant see where the problem is. I did as you did creating a Receta object and adding to it, and then this one to the list but nothing. As Im working with RDF I get Literals and RDFNodes. Thats doesnt suppose to be the problem.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The problem is coming from the JSP, exactly from the forEach I think, cause the rec object have information, and even if I print all the receipes without any table like: <td>${AllReceipes}</td> I get all the data. I dont understand...

Comment: The JSP looks fine to me.                                                                                      Try to insert fictional and simple Receta objects in the List<Receta>  in order to see where the problem resides in the JSP or in the generetion of the List.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I will, as soon as I get the answer I will let you know. Thank you

Comment: I just solved the problem and edited the answer with it. It was as stupid as add the jstl at the beginning of the line and the forEach as: <td><c:out value="${receipt.nombreReceta}"/></td>

Comment: I'm glad it works but there's got to be something else you are messing with, since the two forms of printing data to an HTML page are almost equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423598/jsp-jstl-using-or-not-using-cout-tags

Comment: Actually the problem was that I forget to add the jstl. With both forEach works properly. Thank you for the point :)