# Why would anyone use ${someVar} over <c:out value="${someVar}" />

Tags: html, jsp, escaping, html-escape-characters

Using Spring MVC with JSP:

After some reading, I came to the conclusion, that if I print some value using

`${someValue}`

no html escaping is done. This is a problem since I want to print texts containing `<` `>` etc.

The solution I am going to use is to replace all occurencies of this kind using the `<c:out>`-tag like

`<c:out value="${someValue}" />`

My question is: Why would I want to use the short form in the first place?

The only valid usage I'd imagine would be, if I want to render the content of **someValue** as html (which in my opinion is rather the exceptional case).

**EDIT: I've found another post which answers my question about when to use the short form, it can be found here**

[XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

As stated in the link, it is important to wrap **user-controlled input which is being re-displayed** since this is the potential source for an attack.

So, if some value does not have any special characters e.g. like `<` or `>` and is not a value generated or controlled by the user, the shorthand form `${someValue}` can be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP/JSTL using or not using <c:out> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423598/jsp-jstl-using-or-not-using-cout-tags)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this link. I've edited my question trying to explain the difference and proposed a conclusion.